# UITapGestureRecognizer Add Coordinates to an Array

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uiimageview, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have an `ImageView` inside of a `ScrollView`.
Each time the user clicks on a point on the image a pin is set and the `coordinates` are printed out.

However, I'm trying to store multiple `coordinates` inside of an array.
The first 3 times the user clicks on the image, I need the coordinates to store inside `refs1`.  The next 14-20 times inside `spots1`.

```
// MARK: - Outlets
@IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!
@IBOutlet weak var sharkImage: UIImageView!

// MARK: - Properties
var refs1 :[Double] = []
var spots1 :[Double] = []

// MARK: - View Did Load
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 1.0
    scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 6.0

    scrollView.delegate = self

    let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tapAction))

    self.sharkImage.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    self.sharkImage.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)
}

// MARK: - Scroll View
func viewForZooming(in scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView? {
    return sharkImage
}

// MARK: - Functions
func tapAction(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    // Get points for the UIImageView
    let touchPoint = sender.location(in: self.sharkImage)
    print(touchPoint)

    // Add pin to tap
    let pin = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: touchPoint.x - 5, y: touchPoint.y - 5, width:10, height:10))
    pin.image = UIImage(named: "photo-pin-red")
    sharkImage.addSubview(pin)

}
```

Comment: What do you mean by **next `14-20` times** is it after the first 3 tap you need to store location in second array spots1 for about 14 or 20 objects ?

Comment: yes it could be anywhere from 14 - 20 taps in addition to the first 3.  so the second counter should be <=23

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well first of all you could store the coordinates in a `2D array` if you want to:

```
var refs1 :[[Double]] = []
var spots1 :[[Double]] = []
```

Then store a global variable called counter to keep track of the click count:

```
var counter = 0
```

And then in your `tapAction` do the following (see comments for descriptions):

```
func tapAction(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    // increase counter with +1 for each click
    counter += 1

    if counter <= 3 { // first 3
        refs1.append([Double(touchPoint.x), Double(touchPoint.y)])
    } else if counter <= 23 { // next 14 - 20 clicks
        counter = 0 // reset counter to start over again
        spots1.append([Double(touchPoint.x), Double(touchPoint.y)])
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Rashwan - the coordinates are the x and y values of a UIImage so not actual map coordinates

Comment: Then you should maybe use a 2D array instead: `var refs1 : [[Double]] = []` To append: `refs1.append([x,y])`. It will be easier for you to keep track of the x, y for each click.

Comment: thanks I did already upvote both your answer and your comment.  The middle statement in the if statement is not working and I also have to edit a few things for it to be completely correct. ie after the first 3 there are an additional 14-20 possible clicks - so I changed it to `counter <=23` and then another `counter > 23`.  Also had to convert the touchpoint values to doubles.

Comment: Okey, want me to help you with anything or update the answer?

Comment: Sure edit the 2 if statement values and add this and I'll mark it as correct 

`// Get points for the UIImageView
        let touchPoint = sender.location(in: self.sharkImage)
        let touchPointValue = [Double(touchPoint.x), Double(touchPoint.y)]`

Comment: Do you mean like this: first 3 clicks then you go into the first if-statement. Then click 14-20 (counter 17 - 23) go to the next if-statment or?

Comment: not quite - so there can be 14-20 clicks after the initial 3 clicks. So the second counter should be `counter <=23` .  Also I'm unsure if my version of swift isn't correct but the `else if counter >= 14 && < 21 ` is producing an error

Comment: Well if you click 3 times first and then you can click additional 14-20 times, then you need to set 3 + 14 and 20 + 3, so the next if-statement should be:
`else if counter >= 17 && counter <= 23`

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question sorry if it isn't worded well...it's not inbetween 14-20 it's INCLUDING all the next 14 to 20 times a user clicks.

Answer (score 0):

Use a counter variable:

```
var count = 0
func tapAction(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    count = conut + 1
    // Check for count
    if (count >= 14) {
        // Do stuff
    }
    // Get points for the UIImageView
    let touchPoint = sender.location(in: self.sharkImage)
    print(touchPoint)

    // Add pin to tap
    let pin = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: touchPoint.x - 5, y: touchPoint.y - 5, width:10, height:10))
    pin.image = UIImage(named: "photo-pin-red")
    sharkImage.addSubview(pin)

}
```